# Updating static resources in Cordova application

Tags: cordova

After a Cordova application has been installed, is it possible to update its underlying static resources?    This would be nice to support updating applications without pushing new versions out to the app store, while continuing to support offline mode (since the web view cache is volatile).

I understand there are a few (and probably more) obvious concerns/problems with attempting something like this:

- App Store rejection
- Application bundle can't be updated at runtime (would have to change the directory where Cordova pulls files)

Has anyone ever attempted something like this before?

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Kinda...  I ended up storing all the web assets in the file system / app sandbox.  I only store the cordova.js + its plugins in the bundle.  Got the same working on Android as well.